# Display total number of rows in footer of devexpress grid

Tags: c#, grid, devexpress

I need to display total number of rows in a grid, in footer.

I have made the footer enable by setting : "this.gridViewTradePoster.OptionsView.ShowFooter = true;", but don't know how to set the text on the footer so that it displays total number of records/row displayed.

i am using Devexpress grid. And it is using C# (.net).

If anyone can help.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at [this](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/CQ64186.aspx) page on the DevExpress Support Center for information on how to do this.